# Change username in Jira and Confluence

Tags: jira, confluence

We're about to move to using Active Directory to authenticate our users to Jira and Confluence. Currently, Confluence uses the Jira user directory. There's only one problem I can see. One user has a mismatched username - on Jira, they're firstname.l, where l is last initial. On AD, they're just firstname. What's the easiest way to change their username to (or move all their stuff to a new user called) firstname?

Comment: This is probably better suited to https://support.atlassian.com/. https://confluence.atlassian.com/conf611/change-a-username-956138216.html appears relevant.

Comment: @ceejayoz The problem is that the documentation is conflicting. That page says "Jira 6.1 or later Rename the user in Jira, Confluence will automatically detect the renamed user.", whereas the page describing how to do it in Jira says that you can't use the normal Jira feature to do that when Confluence is connected. It's unclear whether the XML method would break Confluence.

Comment: Then I'd say your next step is https://support.atlassian.com/contact/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver070/create-edit-or-remove-a-user-794199053.html

> 1. Select [cog] > User Management.
> 2. Find the user in the user list using the filter form at the top of
>      the page.
> 3. Click Edit in the Operations column.
> 4. Make the changes to username, full name, or email address and click
>      Update to finish.

I used this procedure before merging the Jira directory with AD and Confluence updated just fine.

Comment: I finally figured this out by going through the options. Apparently there was just so much documentation about how painful it was in previous versions it made it near impossible to find documentation showing how easy it was in the current version. Thank you!